# Expl3 syntax highlighting for TeXworks

Tags: texworks, expl3

Does anyone have a syntax pattern for TeXworks’s `syntax-patterns.txt` that will correctly highlight Expl3 code? *I.e.*, something that will recognize that the entirety of `\cs_new:Npn` is a command sequence—although highlighting the `:Npn` suffix differently might not be a bad idea.

Comment: nice idea (even though texworks wouldn't be my first choice when writing code :-) )

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129439/17423

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use a colour scheme based loosely on that from [WinEdt](http://www.winedt.com)'s [DTX submode](http://www.winedt.org/Config/modes/DTX.php) (I used to use WinEdt). This is for editing `.dtx` files, and nowadays includes support for `l3docstrip`'s `@@` convention:

```
[LaTeX DTX]

# comments
red        Y    \^\^A.*

# Guards
orange         N    %<(?:[A-Za-z0-9!\|]+|.)>
limegreen      N    %<\*(?:[A-Za-z0-9!\|]+|.)>
crimson        N    %</(?:[A-Za-z0-9!\|]+|.)>
darkviolet     N    %<@@=(?:[A-Za-z]+|.)>

# special characters
darkred        N    \^\^\^\^\^[0-9a-z]{5}
darkred        N    \^\^\^\^[0-9a-z]{4}
darkred        N    \^\^\^[0-9a-z]{3}
darkred        N    \^\^[0-9a-z]{2}
darkred        N    [$#^_{}&]
gray        N    ^%%.*
gray        N    ^%

# Macrocode
green        N    \\(?:begin|end)\{macrocode\}

# LaTeX environments
darkgreen    N    \\(?:begin|end)\s*\{[^}]*\}

# control sequences
blue        N    \\(?:[A-Za-z@:_]+|.)
```

The key line here is the last one, which does the highlighting request. Of course, this is just a case of getting the regular expression right (if only this were easy!).

Comment: I’d been using a version of this (without the @@-highlighting) based on an earlier answer of yours, and didn’t realize it already covered expl3. Thank you!