# LaTeX3-sensitive editors

Tags: editors, latex3, expl3, winedt

I'm starting to embed `LaTeX3` code in my custom classes and packages -- and enjoying it more the further I learn about it --, but at least to me it would make for an even better experience if, as it is common in the computer languages I work with regularly, I could use some editor sensitive to `LaTeX3` in terms, at least, of highlighting.

It may be a little too early for this, given that the interface (and the implementation itself, as far as my knowledge goes) is still work in progress and not everything that is already available is stable, but entire stability (if there is such a thing) may be far ahead on the road and it seems to me that we already have elements considered stable enough for us to benefit from such editing features.

True, one could always setup a favorite text editor accordingly (`WinEdt` is my regular editor for all things TeX, but I'm not committed to any editor in particular), but I'm asking for something already made... and trying to bring the attention of developers to this topic.

Anyone knows of some editor out there with this kind of features? Are there any projects in this direction?

Comment: If you are after highlighting for `expl3`, any decent editor allows customisation. There are lots of editors out there, and it's not clear to me that you need a special one for `expl3` code, just the appropriate settings if that it how you like to work. (I just use the same TeXworks settings I have for `.dtx` editing generally. I probably should make some rules for `expl3` highlighting!)

Comment: @Joseph Wright: Right, I was not asking for a particular editor just for ``expl3`` syntax, but for any who did already embed rules for highlighting that syntax. I believe that in order to be able to set my editor in that regard in an effective way I still need to know a lot more about LaTeX3 than I do now. Btw, let me say that I just read today your TUGboat article on l3keys and it was instrumental in my becoming able to start using LaTeX3 for the keys in my classes and packages. I wonder why these articles are not included in the documentation.

Comment: On the articles, they are a bit piecemeal. What we really need is a proper beginners guide, but that's hard to write!

Comment: I would like to make an add-on for WinEdt, if I only knew what exactly has to be highlighted... Unfortunately (my fault) I've never started learning LaTeX3.

Comment: @karlkoeller: Well, to me at least having such an add-on for ``WinEdt`` would be great, because this is my favorite editor-(sort of) IDE for everything TeX-based (on Windows). One of the points I was addressing in my answer to Joseph Wright was precisely about what and how to highlight... I still need to take a close look at his answer, which provides much more than I was expecting of any answer for my post. Maybe by inspecting it you can get insight enough to make some choices on what and howto devide the expl3 syntax highlighting... If you come up with something, please do let me know! ;-)

Comment: @Joseph Wright: Yes, I do feel the need for a proper "young person's guide" ( ;-) ) to ``LaTeX3`` and ``expl3``. But in the meantime what has been helping me most have been those papers, which I believe would be worthy additions to the official documentation in the different distributions (MiKTeX, TeX Live...)

Comment: May I add that probably this website would benefit from  LaTeX3 highlighting? Currently the highlighter does a rather poor job with expl3 syntax...

Comment: @Marcos Oh, the young can learn anything. It is us older ones who need a guide the most!

Comment: Does anybody know if there are syntax files available for kile or kate? Or vim?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### Update (2017-02-14)

Thanks to the time spent on the answer below, and to some new features in WinEdt 10.2, now WinEdt 10.2 is really *"LaTeX3-sensitive"*.

WinEdt 10.2 incorporates the highlighting scheme in this answer (with many improvements) and features many other functionalities to support LaTeX3 (e.g. command completion for commands and environments defined with `\NewDocumentCommand`, `\NewDocumentEnvironment` and alike).

---

### Complete Highlighting Scheme for WinEdt

This is a highlighting scheme for `expl3` in WinEdt 8.

**New: It is now available as an add-on:** [**LaTeX3**](http://www.winedt.org/config/modes/LaTeX3.html)

---

### Highlighting LaTeX3 guards in `.dtx` files

Add the following lines in `Switches.ini` just before the switch `SWITCH="DTX Single Guard"`

```
SWITCH="DTX LaTeX3 Guard"
  ENABLED=1
  MODE_FILTER="DTX"
  START="DTX %"
  STOP=">"
  HIGHLIGHT_START=1
  STEP_OVER_STOP=1
  HIGHLIGHT_STOP=1
  SCOPE=1
  DOMINANT_PRIORITY=0
  STRICT_PRIORITY=1
  PRIORITY=9
  INDENTED=0
  BOLN_ONLY=1
  CASE_SENSITIVE=1
  START1_TRIGGER=""
  START2_TRIGGER="<@@="
  STOP1_TRIGGER=""
  STOP2_TRIGGER=""
    TEXT_COLOR=5
    BACKGROUND_RGB="$F8F8F8"
    TRANSPARENT=144
    DEFAULT_FONT=1
```

Result:

[image]

### Collecting LaTeX3 guards in the "Tree"

Add the following lines in `Tree.ini` inside the branch `BRANCH="Guards-DTX"`, just between the lines `END="</?>"` and `ITEM="<?>"`

```
  ITEM="<@@=?>"
    MODE_FILTER="DTX"
    CASE_SENSITIVE=1
    LINE_START="%"
    BEGINNING_OF_LINE_ONLY=2
    CURRENT_DOCUMENT_ONLY=1
    ALL_OPENED_DOCUMENTS=0
    COMPLETE_PROJECT_TREE=1
    ICON="ArrowPurple"
    LEVEL=0
    CAPTION="%?"
    MAX_LINE_SPAN=1
    ON_CTRL_CLICK_MACRO="GlobalMark;TreeTrack(2);"
    ON_CLICK_MACRO="TreeTrack(2,1);"
    ON_DBL_CLICK_MACRO="TreeTrack(2,2);"
    ACTION="Find"
      IMAGE="Find"
      MACRO="TreeTrack(2);"
  END="<@@=?>"
```

Result:

[image]

### Highlighting LaTeX3 commands

Add the following lines in `FilterSets.ini` just before the set `FILTER_SET="~AlphaNumeric"`

```
FILTER_SET="~Alpha@_:"
  ENABLED=0
  MODE_FILTER=""
  SET=:~(Alpha+["@_:"])
  BEFORE=""
  AFTER=""
  BOLN_NOT_OK=0
  EOLN_NOT_OK=0
  STRICT_PRIORITY=0
  PRIORITY=0
    DEFAULT_FONT=1
```

Then, in `Switches.ini`, in the switch `SWITCH="\"`, replace the line

```
STOP="~Alpha@"
```

with

```
STOP="~Alpha@_:"
```

Finally, in `Keywords.ini`, replace all occurrences of

```
AFTER="~Alpha@"
```

with

```
AFTER="~Alpha@_:"
```

Result:

[image]

### Highlighting LaTeX3 Kernel keywords

Add the following lines in `Switches.ini` just before the switch `SWITCH="\"`

```
SWITCH="LaTeX3 Kernel Engine Prefixes"
  ENABLED=1
  MODE_FILTER="TeX"
  START="\"
  STOP="~Alpha@_:"
  HIGHLIGHT_START=1
  STEP_OVER_STOP=0
  HIGHLIGHT_STOP=0
  SCOPE=0
  DOMINANT_PRIORITY=0
  STRICT_PRIORITY=0
  PRIORITY=5
  INDENTED=0
  BOLN_ONLY=0
  CASE_SENSITIVE=1
  START1_TRIGGER=""
  START2_TRIGGER="luatex_if_engine"
  START2_TRIGGER="pdftex_if_engine"
  START2_TRIGGER="xetex_if_engine"
  STOP1_TRIGGER=""
  STOP2_TRIGGER=""
    TEXT_COLOR=5
    DEFAULT_FONT=1
    BOLD=1

SWITCH="LaTeX3 Kernel Prefixes"
  ENABLED=1
  MODE_FILTER="TeX"
  START="\"
  STOP="~Alpha@_:"
  HIGHLIGHT_START=1
  STEP_OVER_STOP=0
  HIGHLIGHT_STOP=0
  SCOPE=0
  DOMINANT_PRIORITY=0
  STRICT_PRIORITY=0
  PRIORITY=5
  INDENTED=0
  BOLN_ONLY=0
  CASE_SENSITIVE=1
  START1_TRIGGER=""
  START2_TRIGGER="alloc_"
  START2_TRIGGER="bool_"
  START2_TRIGGER="box_"
  START2_TRIGGER="cctab_"
  START2_TRIGGER="char_"
  START2_TRIGGER="chk_"
  START2_TRIGGER="clist_"
  START2_TRIGGER="codedoc_"
  START2_TRIGGER="coffin_"
  START2_TRIGGER="color_"
  START2_TRIGGER="cs_"
  START2_TRIGGER="dim_"
  START2_TRIGGER="driver_"
  START2_TRIGGER="else_"
  START2_TRIGGER="etex_"
  START2_TRIGGER="exp_"
  START2_TRIGGER="expl_"
  START2_TRIGGER="fi_"
  START2_TRIGGER="fp_"
  START2_TRIGGER="group_"
  START2_TRIGGER="hbox_"
  START2_TRIGGER="hcoffin_"
  START2_TRIGGER="if_"
  START2_TRIGGER="insert_"
  START2_TRIGGER="int_"
  START2_TRIGGER="kernel_"
  START2_TRIGGER="keys_"
  START2_TRIGGER="keyval_"
  START2_TRIGGER="lua_"
  START2_TRIGGER="luatex_"
  START2_TRIGGER="mode_"
  START2_TRIGGER="muskip_"
  START2_TRIGGER="or_"
  START2_TRIGGER="pdftex_"
  START2_TRIGGER="peek_"
  START2_TRIGGER="prop_"
  START2_TRIGGER="quark_"
  START2_TRIGGER="reverse_"
  START2_TRIGGER="seq_"
  START2_TRIGGER="skip_"
  START2_TRIGGER="str_"
  START2_TRIGGER="tex_"
  START2_TRIGGER="tl_"
  START2_TRIGGER="token_"
  START2_TRIGGER="use_"
  START2_TRIGGER="vbox_"
  START2_TRIGGER="vcoffin_"
  START2_TRIGGER="xetex_"
  STOP1_TRIGGER=""
  STOP2_TRIGGER=""
    TEXT_COLOR=4
    DEFAULT_FONT=1
    BOLD=1

SWITCH="LaTeX3 File Handling"
  ENABLED=1
  MODE_FILTER="TeX"
  START="\"
  STOP="~Alpha@_:"
  HIGHLIGHT_START=1
  STEP_OVER_STOP=0
  HIGHLIGHT_STOP=0
  SCOPE=0
  DOMINANT_PRIORITY=0
  STRICT_PRIORITY=0
  PRIORITY=5
  INDENTED=0
  BOLN_ONLY=0
  CASE_SENSITIVE=1
  START1_TRIGGER=""
  START2_TRIGGER="file_"
  START2_TRIGGER="g_file_"
  START2_TRIGGER="ior_"
  START2_TRIGGER="iow_"
  START2_TRIGGER="l_ior_"
  START2_TRIGGER="l_iow_"
  STOP1_TRIGGER=""
  STOP2_TRIGGER=""
   TEXT_COLOR=2
   DEFAULT_FONT=1
   BOLD=1

SWITCH="LaTeX3 Package Messages"
 ENABLED=1
 MODE_FILTER="TeX"
 START="\"
 STOP="~Alpha@_:"
 HIGHLIGHT_START=1
 STEP_OVER_STOP=0
 HIGHLIGHT_STOP=0
 SCOPE=0
 DOMINANT_PRIORITY=0
 STRICT_PRIORITY=0
 PRIORITY=5
 INDENTED=0
 BOLN_ONLY=0
 CASE_SENSITIVE=1
 START1_TRIGGER=""
 START2_TRIGGER="msg_"
 STOP1_TRIGGER=""
 STOP2_TRIGGER=""
  TEXT_COLOR=9
  DEFAULT_FONT=1
  ITALIC=1

SWITCH="LaTeX3 NoOp Functions"
 ENABLED=1
 MODE_FILTER="TeX"
 START="\"
 STOP="~Alpha@_:"
 HIGHLIGHT_START=1
 STEP_OVER_STOP=0
 HIGHLIGHT_STOP=0
 SCOPE=0
 DOMINANT_PRIORITY=0
 STRICT_PRIORITY=0
 PRIORITY=5
 INDENTED=0
 BOLN_ONLY=0
 CASE_SENSITIVE=1
 START1_TRIGGER=""
 START2_TRIGGER="prg_"
 START2_TRIGGER="scan_"
 STOP1_TRIGGER=""
 STOP2_TRIGGER=""
  TEXT_COLOR=3
  DEFAULT_FONT=1
  BOLD=1
```

Then, add the following lines in `Keywords.ini` just before the group `KEYWORD_GROUP="TeX Units"`

```
KEYWORD_GROUP="LaTeX3  Keywords"
  ENABLED=1
  MODE_FILTER="TeX"
  BEFORE="\ (single)"
  AFTER="~Alpha@_:"
  BOLN_NOT_OK=1
  EOLN_NOT_OK=0
  STRICT_PRIORITY=0
  PRIORITY=6
  CASE_SENSITIVE=1
    TEXT_COLOR=0
    DEFAULT_FONT=1
    BOLD=1
    UNDERLINE=1
LIST="END_LIST"
ExplSyntaxOff
ExplSyntaxOn
END_LIST

KEYWORD_GROUP="LaTeX3  Keywords..."
  ENABLED=1
  MODE_FILTER="TeX"
  BEFORE="\ (single)"
  AFTER="~Alpha@_:"
  BOLN_NOT_OK=1
  EOLN_NOT_OK=0
  STRICT_PRIORITY=0
  PRIORITY=6
  CASE_SENSITIVE=1
    TEXT_COLOR=4
    DEFAULT_FONT=1
    BOLD=1
LIST="END_LIST"
DeclareDocumentCommand
DeclareDocumentEnvironment
NewDocumentCommand
NewDocumentEnvironment
ProvideDocumentCommand
ProvideDocumentEnvironment
RenewDocumentCommand
RenewDocumentEnvironment
END_LIST
```

Result:

[image]

### Highlight LaTeX3 properties & constants

This is the best that can be done for this one.

Add the following lines in `FilterSets.ini` just before the set `FILTER_SET="="`

```
FILTER_SET="."
  ENABLED=0
  MODE_FILTER=""
  SET=:["."]
  BEFORE=""
  AFTER=""
  BOLN_NOT_OK=0
  EOLN_NOT_OK=0
  STRICT_PRIORITY=0
  PRIORITY=0
    DEFAULT_FONT=1
```

Then, add the following lines in `Switches.ini` just before the switch `SWITCH="\"` (after the newly defined switch `SWITCH="LaTeX3 Kernel Prefixes"`)

```
SWITCH="LaTeX3 Properties"
  ENABLED=1
  MODE_FILTER="TeX"
  START="."
  STOP=":"
  HIGHLIGHT_START=1
  STEP_OVER_STOP=1
  HIGHLIGHT_STOP=1
  SCOPE=0
  DOMINANT_PRIORITY=0
  STRICT_PRIORITY=0
  PRIORITY=5
  INDENTED=0
  BOLN_ONLY=0
  CASE_SENSITIVE=1
  START1_TRIGGER=""
  START2_TRIGGER="code"
  START2_TRIGGER="choice"
  START2_TRIGGER="choice_code"
  START2_TRIGGER="generate_choices"
  START2_TRIGGER="initial"
  START2_TRIGGER="default"
  START2_TRIGGER="meta"
  START2_TRIGGER="alloc_"
  START2_TRIGGER="bool_"
  START2_TRIGGER="box_"
  START2_TRIGGER="cctab_"
  START2_TRIGGER="char_"
  START2_TRIGGER="chk_"
  START2_TRIGGER="clist_"
  START2_TRIGGER="codedoc_"
  START2_TRIGGER="coffin_"
  START2_TRIGGER="color_"
  START2_TRIGGER="cs_"
  START2_TRIGGER="dim_"
  START2_TRIGGER="driver_"
  START2_TRIGGER="else_"
  START2_TRIGGER="etex_"
  START2_TRIGGER="exp_"
  START2_TRIGGER="expl_"
  START2_TRIGGER="fi_"
  START2_TRIGGER="file_"
  START2_TRIGGER="fp_"
  START2_TRIGGER="group_"
  START2_TRIGGER="hbox_"
  START2_TRIGGER="hcoffin_"
  START2_TRIGGER="if_"
  START2_TRIGGER="insert_"
  START2_TRIGGER="int_"
  START2_TRIGGER="ior_"
  START2_TRIGGER="iow_"
  START2_TRIGGER="kernel_"
  START2_TRIGGER="keys_"
  START2_TRIGGER="keyval_"
  START2_TRIGGER="lua_"
  START2_TRIGGER="luatex_"
  START2_TRIGGER="mode_"
  START2_TRIGGER="msg_"
  START2_TRIGGER="muskip_"
  START2_TRIGGER="or_"
  START2_TRIGGER="pdftex_"
  START2_TRIGGER="peek_"
  START2_TRIGGER="prg_"
  START2_TRIGGER="prop_"
  START2_TRIGGER="quark_"
  START2_TRIGGER="reverse_"
  START2_TRIGGER="scan_"
  START2_TRIGGER="seq_"
  START2_TRIGGER="skip_"
  START2_TRIGGER="str_"
  START2_TRIGGER="tex_"
  START2_TRIGGER="tl_"
  START2_TRIGGER="token_"
  START2_TRIGGER="use_"
  START2_TRIGGER="vbox_"
  START2_TRIGGER="vcoffin_"
  START2_TRIGGER="xetex_"
  STOP1_TRIGGER=""
  STOP2_TRIGGER="n"
  STOP2_TRIGGER="N"
  STOP2_TRIGGER="x"
    TEXT_COLOR=1
    DEFAULT_FONT=1
    ITALIC=1

SWITCH="LaTeX3 Kernel Constants"
  ENABLED=1
  MODE_FILTER="TeX"
  START="\"
  STOP="~Alpha@_:"
  HIGHLIGHT_START=1
  STEP_OVER_STOP=0
  HIGHLIGHT_STOP=0
  SCOPE=0
  DOMINANT_PRIORITY=0
  STRICT_PRIORITY=0
  PRIORITY=5
  INDENTED=0
  BOLN_ONLY=0
  CASE_SENSITIVE=1
  START1_TRIGGER=""
  START2_TRIGGER="c_"
  STOP1_TRIGGER=""
  STOP2_TRIGGER=""
    TEXT_COLOR=6
    DEFAULT_FONT=1
    ITALIC=1
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I've recently started to (try to) learn something about LaTeX3, and this add-on you've made for WinEdt is great. As the others you've made, which I daily use for my work, they have saved me a lot of time. So I've decided to award you a bounty, not only for this answer, but for all the add-ons you've made and I use. This is nothing for me compared with the help you've given me with your work. Thanks, Karl.

Comment: @Sterry I don't have words to thank you, both for the bounty and for the compliments!!!!

Answer (score 29):

For the record, here's my font-lock settings for Emacs with LaTeX3.  To make use of these, I define a `latex3-mode` which is derived from the inbuild `latex-mode`.  (Note: I don't use AucTeX, I use the simple TeX modes.)  The idea of the font-locking is similar to Joseph's in that it adds more matches for highlighting.  I've added a `specials` for core functions (probably not included them all as yet).  There's also a distinction between macros with a `_` and ones without (such as ordinary LaTeX2e macros/functions and the `xparse` ones).  I could probably do with defining a few more faces to further distinguish, but this is currently working well enough for me.

```lisp
(defconst latex3-font-lock-keywords
   (eval-when-compile
     (let* (;; Commands relevant to data structures
            (specials "\\(bool\\|char\\|clist\\|cs\\|exp\\|file\\|group\\|keys\\|prop\\|q\\|seq\\|tl\\)_[a-zA-Z_:]+")
            (general "\\([a-zA-Z_:]+\\)")
            (camel "\\([a-zA-Z@]+\\)")
            (nocamel "\\(?:[^a-zA-Z@_:]\\)")
            (slash "\\\\")
            )
       (list
        (list (concat "\\(" slash specials "\\)")
              1 'font-lock-function-name-face)
        (list (concat "\\(" slash camel "\\)" nocamel) 1 'font-lock-function-name-face)
        (list (concat "\\(" slash general "\\)") 1 'font-lock-variable-name-face)
        )
       )
     )
  "Extra commands to highlight in LaTeX3 modes."
  )

(define-derived-mode latex3-mode latex-mode "LaTeX3"
  "Major mode to edit LaTeX3 files."
  (set (make-local-variable 'font-lock-defaults)
       '((tex-font-lock-keywords latex3-font-lock-keywords) 
         nil nil ((?$ . "\"")) nil
         ;; Who ever uses that anyway ???
         (font-lock-mark-block-function . mark-paragraph)
         (font-lock-syntactic-face-function
          . tex-font-lock-syntactic-face-function)
         (font-lock-unfontify-region-function
          . tex-font-lock-unfontify-region)
         (font-lock-syntactic-keywords
          . tex-font-lock-syntactic-keywords)
         (parse-sexp-lookup-properties . t)))
 )

(add-hook 'latex3-mode-hook (function (lambda () (setq ispell-parser 'tex))))
(add-hook 'latex3-mode-hook '(lambda () (flyspell-mode 0)))
```

Here's a screenshot (where you can see that I should add `box` and `vbox` to my list of special functions):

[image: Emacs with L3 font-locking]

Comment: There is a list of all module prefixes in https://github.com/latex3/svn-mirror/blob/master/l3kernel/l3prefixes.csv if you want to have a 'definitive' reference for the kernel ones.

Comment: I should add that suggestions for improvements would be more than welcome!

Comment: In a way, I'm glad you beat me to it. +1! One question though: Is the pilcrow being inserted by the settings you've given, or are those your own personal preference?

Comment: @SeanAllred I'm guessing that the `pilcrow` is the newline mark.  It's put there by `longlines-mode`, which I use to make it so that I can write one sentence per line in my normal LaTeX documents.  I guess it doesn't make as much sense in a package but then I never claimed to have everything set up perfectly.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Seems like a nice setup to me :) I doubt the pilcrow is actually there---it's probably an overlay---but I can definitely see it helping when text is wrapped at the window's edge.

Comment: @SeanAllred The pilcrow's distinguish between "hard" new lines and "soft" new lines.  Those with a pilcrow are "hard" and will be preserved when the file is written out.  Those without are "soft" and will be removed when the file is written out.

Comment: A `vim` syntax file, please :-)

Comment: Note additionally that there has been [a posting to the AUCTeX-devel mailing list](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.auctex.devel/3794) about adding expl3 syntax support.

Comment: @SeanAllred I tried [expl3.el from your post here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/auctex-devel/2015-04/msg00000.html) and it works pretty reasonably; any idea why it never got into the AUCTeX tree?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I'm glad it works for you! I'm still working on getting FSF copyright assignment from my employer :-(

Comment: @SeanAllred I would like to try the `expl3.el`. How should I load it?

Comment: @TeXtnik You should just be able to `(load "expl3.el")`. Is that not working?

Comment: @SeanAllred It doesn't seem to do anything on my `.dtx` file. The macros are only highlighted up to the first appearance of `_`. The funny thing is that if I open `xparse.dtx` all the macros are highlighted properly.

Answer (score 24):

[TeXworks](http://tug.org/texworks) uses a simple regex-based approach to syntax highlighting, with the information stored in the file `syntax-patterns.txt` inside the folder `TeXworks/configuration`, which lives in a system-dependent location. I have a set of patterns for working with `.dtx` (LaTeX documented source) files, which include highlighting for `expl3` code:

```
[LaTeX DTX]

# comments
red        Y    \^\^A.*

# Guards
orange         N    %<(?:[A-Za-z0-9!\|]+|.)>
limegreen      N    %<\*(?:[A-Za-z0-9!\|]+|.)>
crimson        N    %</(?:[A-Za-z0-9!\|]+|.)>
darkviolet     N    %<@@=(?:[A-Za-z]+|.)>

# special characters
darkred        N    \^\^\^\^\^[0-9a-z]{5}
darkred        N    \^\^\^\^[0-9a-z]{4}
darkred        N    \^\^\^[0-9a-z]{3}
darkred        N    \^\^[0-9a-z]{2}
darkred        N    [$#^_{}&]
gray        N    ^%%.*
gray        N    ^%

# Macrocode
green        N    \\(?:begin|end)\{macrocode\}

# LaTeX environments
darkgreen    N    \\(?:begin|end)\s*\{[^}]*\}

# control sequences
blue        N    \\(?:[A-Za-z@:_]+|.)
```

(The colour scheme is based on that used by WinEdt for `.dtx` editing, as I used to use WinEdt.)

The key line is the last one, as regex `\\(?:[A-Za-z@:_]+|.)` matches both `expl3` and 'standard' LaTeX2e macro names. If you wanted to only highlight `expl3` code-level macros in one colour, you could go with something like

```
# functions
blue        N    \\(?:[A-Za-z_]+):(?:[A-Za-z_:]+|.)
# Variables
blue    N    \\(?:[A-Za-z_]+)_(?:[A-Za-z_]+|.)
```

which then won't highlight document/design level (just letter in the name) or LaTeX2e internal (`@` in the name) control sequences. You could of course get more sophisticated and give them all different highlighting! You could also extend the regexes in the way Andrew Stacey does in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129521) to differentiate `expl3` core and 'additional' names, using a more sophisticated set of regexes.

Note that I've also extended the `.dtx` guards recognised to cover the `%<@@=...>` one that `l3doscrip` adds to the 'standard' set, for marking internal names. It's covered by the line

```
darkviolet     N    %<@@=(?:[A-Za-z]+|.)>
```

where I had to find a new colour to fit in with those that were already in use!

Comment: Note: I am no regex expert. My edits to the TeXworks standard set up work more by luck than design :-)

Comment: Since I've made the DTX highlighting scheme in WinEdt, can you tell me what is missing there so I will be able to enhance it?

Comment: This makes for much more than I was expecting from an answer to my question. I still have to look more closely into it, but I'm sure it's going to prove very helpful as a reference to develop some configuration script for an editor. Although it is discouraged doing so on this site, let me thank you for your answer and for your great work on the LaTeX3 stuff.

Comment: @karlkoeller To the '`.dtx` set' from WinEdt I've added one thing and made one alteration. `l3docstrip` has an additional guard type, `%<@@=...>`, which is covered by `%<@@=(?:[A-Za-z]+|.)>` and I made dark violet. For command names, I had to extend the characters included to not just `a-zAZ` and `@` but also `_` and `:`, which is what `\\(?:[A-Za-z@:_]+|.)` does. Note that I started 'from scratch', taking only the colour scheme from WinEdt but not any actual matching code (does WinEdt use regexes?).

Comment: Obviously, any other editor using a regex-based approach can be modified in a similar way.

Comment: WinEdt can match things like those but with a different approach. Guards like `%<@@=...>` can only occur in `.dtx` files, while extended commands can occur in every file, am I right?

Comment: @karlkoeller As I say in the answer, I've set this up for working with `.dtx` files. You are correct that `%<@@=...>` should only appear in a LaTeX3 `.dtx`, while `expl3` code could in principal appear elsewhere (a `.sty` file, for example). My working model is that apart from 'quick tests' `expl3` code should be properly set up in files I edit in `.dtx` mode, so for 'user level' documents I don't need to extend highlighting. That's of course not a technical judgement, it's about how you want to work.

Comment: In my case, since I write my own custom classes and packages for personal, academic, and professional use, but not thinking of attaching to or embedding into them anything serious in terms of documentation, it is ``.cls`` and ``.sty`` files that I work with the most. So, that's the kind of scenario I was thinking about when making my OP -- which of course does not exclude Joseph Wright's emphasis on ``.dtx``.

Comment: Where can I find a list of keywords of LaTeX3 kernel?

Comment: @karlkoeller See [my comment to Andrew](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129439/latex3-sensitive-editors/129458?noredirect=1#comment291791_129521)

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, but (forgive me) I'm not able to retrieve any info from there.

Comment: @karlkoeller It's a CSV file of all 'registered' prefixes: all of those in `expl3` are in the `l3kernel` module. For example, this includes `\box_...`, `\tl_...`, _etc._ Ping me in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) if that doesn't help.

Comment: @JosephWright OK, got it!

Answer (score 6):

**Visual Studio Code** with the extension **LaTeX Workshop** (> v3.5.0) can support LaTeX3 syntax now:

[image]