# expl3 syntax highlight in emacs

Tags: expl3, auctex

AucTeX is not highlighting properly the `expl3` code; not in the `.dtx` file, not in the derived `.sty` file. The macros are not highlighted after the first occurrence of `_`.

Should I some how manually load the `expl3.el` file when programming in `expl3`?

Comment: Does this answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129521/136923) help you?

Comment: @Stone-Zeng My search was narrowed to `expl3` and I don't realise that I should also search for latex3. Thanks for the link, it may help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue you describe is [fixed upstream](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/commit/font-latex.el?id=cd28c6f3b751c8c535b2cc3b0451a90f9430b642) in current version (11.91) of AUCTeX.  For me, `xparse.dtx` is fontified like this:

[image]

Please update your AUCTeX and try it again.  I admit that the solution just works in `.dtx` files and not in `.sty`.  This should be fixed; maybe you can submit a bug report.

---

AUCTeX is capable to parse your `.dtx` or `.sty` in order to find out which package(s) you're using and load the respective style file(s).  Just add the following line to your `.dtx`:

```
\RequirePackage{expl3}
```

After that, you can hit `C-c C-n` to parse the file.  With this line in your `.emacs`:

```lisp
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
```

AUCTeX parses your file directly when you open it.

Comment: I acutaly load `xparse.dtx` with version 11.90 and it looks fine! I installed the 11.91 and the problem persists. It seems that AucTeX doesn't know that my `.dtx` is using `expl3`. Should I have something in the code that AUCTeX should parse?

Comment: Are you explicitly loading expl3 in the dtx? Or is it loaded through other packages?

Comment: @TeXtnik - See update in my answer.

Comment: @ArashEsbati, Loading the `expl3` package doesn't make my Emacs and AUCTeX that colorful, it would do it for an LaTeX2e file.  Also, I'd expect Emacs to detect `\ProvidesEpxlPackage` and act accordingly, which it ignores.  The "auto" file does not add the expl3 style hook in that case.

Comment: Above @stone-zeng linked to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129521/136923, where you could see some examples of other editors.  Any other mentioned editor is more fancy, than emacs. :-(