# TexStudio highlighting expl3 commands as error?

Tags: texstudio, expl3

I am using TexStudio. When using `expl3`-commands the syntax highlighting does not work for the whole command and instead everything with an underscore is marked as an error:

[image: wrong syntax highlighting with expl3 and TexStudio]

I had found [Expl3 syntax highlighting for TeXworks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65764/expl3-syntax-highlighting-for-texworks) and edited the control sequences part and restarted TexStudio but it seems to have no effect...

Comment: Related issue https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/61